# Set extra field in zend logger on user login

Tags: logging, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm trying to update a column mapping value when a user logs in.

Currently, my logger is initialized as follows:

```
$columnMap = [
                'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
                'priority' => 'priority',
                'priorityName' => 'priorityName',
                'message' => 'message',
                'extra' => array(
                    'userid' => 'userid'
                )
];

$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Db($dbAdapter,'logs',$columnMap);
$formatter = new \Zend\Log\Formatter\Db();
$formatter->setDateTimeFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$writer->setFormatter($formatter);
$this->logger->addWriter($writer);
```

What I'd like to do is update the `userid extra field` when a user logs in. Most likely will occur inside the `Module Class`. Id have access to the logger through the service manager.

Comment: Can you please tell how you do a login? Do you use zend-authentication during the login process? and can you use identity plugin in your controllers?

Comment: @tasmaniski yes i am using zend authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a listener for this. Something along the lines of this might suit your need:

```
<?php

namespace Authentication\Listener;

use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class addFieldListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    //@todo add annotations
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listeners = [];

    // @todo strict type
    public function __construct($logger)
    {
        $this->setLogger($logger);
    }

    //You might have to change the priority, which is currently 1,
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, [$this, 'addField'], $priority);
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function addField()
    {
        //Get logger and add field.
    }

    //Getters & setters.. ?
}
```

**Config: module.config.php**

```
<?php

use Authentication\Listener\addFieldListener;

return [
    'listeners' => [
        addFieldListener::class,
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            addFieldListener::class => addFieldListenerFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Note:** Make sure the factory provides the logger to the listener.

Comment: Yes but how do I actually set the field

Comment: Looking at the docs, I can see that there is a `getWriters() : SplPriorityQueue` function. Maybe that can be of some use in combination with the `extract()` function that is available on the SplPriorityQueue instance? I don't have a setup at the moment that allows me to duplicate your issue, so I'm just speculating.

Comment: Yeh I'm not home right now but I need a complete answer for the bounty

Comment: Well if you could extract & then insert again with the updated fields, than that would fix your issue. Again, just speculating as I cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: K I'll try that when I get home

Comment: Were you able to make any progress?

Comment: i havent had the opportunity to implement will be doing later tonight.

Comment: I just saw your comment about you using the Zend AuthenticationService. You could create a session once someone visits your website which you modify once the user logs in. That would be easy.

Comment: Yeh thats the plan i just needed to know how to set the event userid inside the logger its not very documented. Once they log in i update the logger with the userid